# How to Distinguish When a 404 Status is Real in RESTFul Service

Tags: rest, http-response

We have ServiceA with these endpoints defined:

```
/devices:
  get:
    queryParameters:
      make:
        type: string
        repeat: false
        required: false
      model:
        type: string
        repeat: false
        required: false
    responses:
      200:
        body:
            schema: Devices
        500:
          body:
               text/plain:
  /{deviceId}:
    uriParameters:
      deviceId:
    get:
      responses:
        200:
          body:
            schema: Device
        404:
          body:
               text/plain:
        500:
          body:
               text/plain:
```

If no devices match a request to /devices?make=x&model=y, an empty list of devices is returned with a 200 status.  If no device matches a request to /devices/badDeviceID, a 404 is returned.

We have another service which calls this one.  The problem we're encountering is that we want to return a 500 service error from the second service if the first service is down.  If a 404 is returned from the server for calls to /devices?make=x&model=y, we know the service is actually down/unreachable.  But for calls to /devices/badDeviceID, we can't tell if the device just doesn't exist or the service is down.

Has anyone else had this situation?  How did you handle it?

Our services are written in Java and deployed to an application container, in our case JBoss EAP.  If EAP is up and running but the individual service is not deployed or currently disabled, EAP will return a 404 to the caller.  It is this case that we can't distinguish from when the service is deployed/available and the resource couldn't be found.

Comment: Apparently JBoss errors can be configured, at least somewhat.  See here for a starting point: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/271392?_sscc=t

Comment: That sample seems to be changing what page is displayed on a 403 error, not changing the error.  But, I'll dig deeper into the possibility of configuring EAP to return a 500 instead of 404.

Comment: First question. Are you consuming the 1st service directly (ip:port)? Or is there a proxy/gateway? Second question: For what reason do you need to know whether a 404 is due to business or due to infraestructure? Is it expected the http client to behave in different ways according to these scenarios?

Comment: Third question: why a valid query (#1) cause 404 when nothing is found? Is It expected to respond with a single and unique resource? If not, could you return 200 + empty array?

Comment: @Laiv 1. We are connecting via a load balancer but no proxy. 2. The client service should return a 500 error if downstream services are unavailable. Therefore, it needs to differentiate.  3. Yes, the downstream service is expected to return a single/unique resource. If it doesn't exist, as per RESTful convention/standard a 404 is returned.  Empty arrays are expected to be returned when a query returns a collection, not a single instance.

Comment: Not really. A collection of one is still a collection.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the description, you are returning a 404 error in the situation where the service is down or unreachable.  This is not an appropriate response for that situation.  4xx errors are for problems with the user request.  The situation that a service is down or unreachable should be a 5xx error.

Based on the extra detail you provided, I think you can manage this by mapping in a simple app at a less specific context.  For example, say your devices app is mapped on the server at `app/devices`.  You could create a trivial application that you map to `app` that simply returns a 500 class "service down" error.  When the devices app is running, it will be more specific and handle the requests.  If it's not there, your 'service down' web-app takes over.

Comment: Well, that's not exactly clear from the question.  But even if he changed the status code, the problem that he posed still remains: there's no way to tell from just the status code what the specific problem is.  HTTP status codes were never intended to be comprehensive.

Comment: If the service is down, the application container (in our case JBoss EAP) returns a 404.

Comment: @RobertHarvey "If a 404 is returned from the server for calls to /devices?make=x&model=y, we know the service is actually down/unreachable. But for calls to /devices/badDeviceID, we can't tell if the device just doesn't exist or the service is down."  Seems pretty clear to me.  What am I missing?

Comment: @sdoca That's a problem and if you can fix that, you'll be in a better place.   I would recommend moving to an embedded HTTP solution such as embedded Jetty or Tomcat so you won't have a situation where the app server is up but the service is down but I don't know if you can affect that change.

Comment: @JimmyJames Switching servers is not an option for us.

Comment: @sdoca It's been a while since I worked with these things but if you can map a fallback web app that just returns 500 errors to the same path in your server such that your real app shadows/hides it, that might do it.  The app server might balk at two apps mapped to the same context, however.

Answer (score 1):

Do not return a 404 error code, return null

As you have found out, the http return codes are for use by the http protocol layer, not your application layer. Return a 200 and null content, or throw an exception and return 500 if the device id is not found.